# OpenCL - can multiple workers write_image to same coord simultaneously?

Tags: macos, image-processing, kernel, opencl

I have a kernel that takes an image and makes a [waveform out of it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveform_monitor) based on the luminance. In this kernel, workers end up having to write pixels into the exact same spot as other workers. Is this safe?

On my end it looks good (Intel 5000 Graphics) but on a friend's computer with a discrete GPU it seems to be leaking memory or grabbing memory from other areas in the GPU's memory (random images presumably cached in the GPU show up in the rendered image). Is this even where the problem lies? The open source repo is [GCVideoWaveform](https://github.com/gregcotten/GCVideoWaveform). Any thoughts on this are greatly appreciated!

```
int clampInt(int value, int lowerBound, int upperBound){
    if(value < lowerBound){
        return lowerBound;
    }
    if (value > upperBound){
        return upperBound;
    }
    return value;
}
kernel void waveformLuma(read_only image2d_t input, write_only image2d_t output, uint maxValue) {
    size_t x = get_global_id(0);
    size_t y = get_global_id(1);

    uint4 inputColor = read_imageui(input, sampler, (int2)(x,y));

    float luminance01 = (((float)inputColor.x + (float)inputColor.y + (float)inputColor.z) / 3.0) / (float)maxValue;

    int newY = (get_image_dim(output).y - (luminance01*(float)(get_image_dim(output).y-1)));
    newY = clampInt(newY, 0, get_image_dim(output).y-1);

    write_imageui(output, (int2)(x, newY), (uint4)(maxValue, maxValue, maxValue, maxValue));
}
```

### First Computer / Integrated GPU

[image]

### Second Computer / Discrete GPU

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`write_imageui` and `read_imageui` can be called by multiple threads with same parameters, no problem with that. They work as any other assignment operand in OpenCL. 
For example:

```
__private float b = tanh[(global int *)a[2]]; //like read_image, reads from a global memory
(global int *)a[2] = b; //like write image, writes lo a global memory
```

**Note:** *I used a[2], to remark that multiple WI will write to the same location*

---

The `write_imageui` issue is not the problem you are experiencing, the problem is the write operation itself. The results are completely unknown since they heavily depend on WI execution order. In CPU it gives good results (parallel threads, but some underlying sync), while on GPU (fully parallel device) it does not.

However, since the results are "strange", I suggest you think of other problems. I personally don't think that the garbage output is based entirely on this unordered execution behavior.

Comment: It's OK for multiple work items to write the same location, but you don't know which one will "win". I think the issue with the bad output is that some output pixels aren't being written at all and you are seeing garbage left over from previous or other images.

Comment: @Dithermaster - you were right! I forgot to fill the image with a color first.